# python 2.7 presence in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to test a presence of a key in a dictionary as 'if key is not in dictionary: do something'
I have already done this already multiple times, but this time it behaves strangely.

particularly:

```
termCircuit = termCircuitMap[term]
```

returns KeyError

when I debugged this code in Eclipse PyDev, i got the following (using expressions):

```
term in termCircutiMap        # prints False
term in termCircuitMap.keys() # prints True
```

Do anyone understand how this is possible? I thought that if something is 'in' the key set then it is 'in' the dictionary.

I'm attaching a screenshot of the evaluation.

[image: http://img836.imageshack.us/img836/1274/screenshotpython.png]

Thanks a lot for explaining :)

Comment: this is strange... is there any code in between these two conditional statements?

Comment: If you're actually running those two lines in immediate succession there's no explanation for the error.  `key in aDict` is actually faster than and superior to `key in aDict.keys()`, but they _should_ both return the same value.  Is it possible that something has modified the dictionary between those checks?

Comment: Can you show an example of actual code that demonstrates the problem?  What is the type of the keys in your dict?  This behavior could be possible if the keys are objects with incompatible hash/equality definitions.

Comment: It may be because you misspelled `termCircuitMap` in the first test (`term in termCircutiMap`), at least if the script has been directly copied from your program.

Comment: That spelling error... huh if that's true, PyDev has an issue if only one name exists.

Comment: @ASGM: the misspellling is not in the screenshot.  He'd probably get  a NameError before a KeyError if the misspelling was in the actual code.

Comment: I've *removed* the `== True` and `== False` expressions here; they are probably not what you actually entered in your Python prompt and the literal expression `something in somemapping == True` is always going to be `False` due to comparison operator chaining.

Comment: The only way to solve this riddle is to see some actual code. Please post a minimal working example that showcase the issue!

Comment: Does Eclipse PyDev guarantee that the values in the table are updated automatically?  Is there a "refresh" button?

Comment: What is the type of `term`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You might see this behavior if your key's `__hash__` function is not properly defined.  E.g., the following gives roughly the same behavior as you describe:

```
import random

class Evil(int):
    def __hash__(self):
        return random.randint(0, 10000)

evil_vals = [Evil(n) for n in range(10)]

dict_with_evil_keys = dict((evil_val, None)
                           for evil_val in evil_vals)

print evil_vals[0] in dict_with_evil_keys # prints False
print evil_vals[0] in dict_with_evil_keys.keys() # prints True
```

In this case, I'm generating random hash values, which is obviously a bad idea.  A less obvious problem that would have the same effect might be if your key values are mutable.  (Generally, mutable values should never define `__hash__`, and should not be useable as keys in dictionaries.)

Comment: Gah! Took me too long to write the same thing. Only thing I can add is a link to the rules for the `__hash__` method: http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__

Comment: Thank you, apparently the problem was that I thought that the objects are immutable but they were not. So here is the explanation how this situation can happen, if someone is curious:

    o = SomeClass() #wrongly supposed to be immutable

Comment: Ok, sorry guys, I'm to dumb to put code in comments, apparently.

So here is the example:
o = SomeClass()
map[o] = None
#now hash(o) == x
mutate(o)
#now hash(o) == y
o in map #prints False, because the hash of o was x when it was added
o in map.keys() #prints True, because map.keys() is a list and the presence in a list is not checked by computing hash (i guess...)

Comment: Sorry that the code is not fomated I have yet to learn how to do that :-)